# Nose tests and testing libraries

Tags: python-3.x, testing, nose

I have a module which is like so:

```
import A.b
import A.c
if name == "A":
    load_some_settings()
```

in test.py

```
import A
# avoid load_some_settings()
```

Mocking doesn't work here as module is loaded before patching.
I tried importing via `imp.load_source` 
however it loads the module twice, once with the actual name and then by the new name